# How can QGIS be installed without administrative rights?

Tags: qgis

I have the impression from searching that this may have been possible with earlier versions but I don't know if it is possible with version 1.8.

Comment: Which operation system do you use?

Comment: the OS is windows 7

Comment: I have a portable installer which I use for my students. This works, because I have several patch files replacing the original ones while the postinstall runs.

Answer (score 3):

There's another possibility [mentioned here](https://qgis2015.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/how-to-make-a-qgis-on-a-stick-implementation/) by copying dll in a quite complicated way. Below a little extract of the proceedings with the solution that was found :

> If you ask yourself: “And so what ? Why not do an ordinary install of
>   QGIS ?” – You haven’t (as I have) been in a out-of-town computer-lab
>   with 24 computers –  all with non working or not existing QGIS setups
>   and off-course  no IT personnel with local administrator rights nearby
>   and 15 minutes until the first pupils arrive. After that, you most
>   certainly know what I’m talking about !! computerlab
>
> The problem is that QGIS installation process copies some general
>   support dll’s into the windows directory if they are missing before
>   the actual QGIS install.
>
> **The solution was to find which general support dll’s that QGIS uses**
>   **and copy them to a directory included the QGIS installation**. This
>   directory has to be part of the “path” statement for the QGIS startup.
>   There is one obvious candidate for this: The directory
>   ..\apps\qgis\bin where  a number of support dll’s for QGIS already
>   resides.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume the admin rights sought to being avoided are Windows 10 or similar.

I am confident you can use the steps below to create a noAdmin Portable USB for Windows 10 using [QGIS LTR 3.16](https://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.6-1-Setup-x86_64.exe)

***Steps***

0. On Windows download the installer to a USB device. if you have a spare Windows computer that doesn't have the admin issue to skip you can skip steps 1 - 3.
1. Then fire up a laptop with Ubuntu/Debian OS that can run the windows emulator [Wine](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu/).
2. Use the emulator run the QGIS installer from the USB specifying the installation location to also be the same USB device.
3. I used the Linux terminal insturct Wine to run the QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.6-1-Setup-x86_64.exe
4. For tidiness just install the whole program to a folder called 'QGIS' i.e. F:\QGIS.
5. Once the program installed to the USB return to the Admin Windows OS device and insert USB.
6. Locate and modify the qgis-ltr-bin-g7.env file in the ?:\QGIS\bin folder. Note the system allocated drive letter for the usb in my case it was F but it is likely to be different.
7. As shown in the image below the next task is to change the letter drive in the env to the one assigned to the USB (in this instance to F:\ or F:/) just use Notepad and Ctrl+H.

[image]

8. Create a shortcut to point to the executable ?:\QGIS\bin folderqgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe. do not run QGIS at this time as normally a first install will create the profiles path in the C:\users\tony<- This is the principles cause the admin rights issue in the first place. The next steps alter this to create the profiles path in the USB.
9. right clock the newly created shortcut to access the properties. locate the target field and add

   F:\QGIS\bin\qgis-ltr-bin-g7.exe --profiles-path F:\myqgisprofiles\

[image: Shortcut Target Text]

10. Then the Start in field should be set to the root of the drive letter assigned to the USB i.e. F:\
11. press Ok
12. double-click the short cut and congratulations QGIS should start.
13. zip the whole lot up and share it around (780mb).